# How do I run a command remotely as root ？

Tags: linux, expect

I`m trying to login to a server as userA then switch to the root account and run some command. The steps should be like:

1. ssh userA@10.0.0.1
2. su - root
3. whoami

I implemented step 1 with the code below but don't know how to implement steps 2 and 3.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 12
set password_root 12345678
set password_A 12345678

spawn ssh -t sflow@10.0.0.1
expect -re ".*password:"
send "$password_sflow\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Last line, don't use expect eof, but instead expect on the new prompt and keep going with send/expect statements. Read some tutorials, there are good ones to cover your use case. One sample: https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/6294378

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 12
set password_root 12345678
set password_A 12345678

set prompt "#|>|\\\$ $"
spawn ssh -t user1@xxx.xxx.x.xx
expect  {
        timeout {puts TIMEOUT}
        "yes/no" {send "yes\r";exp_continue}
        "password:" {send "user1password\r";exp_continue}
        -re $prompt
}
send "su - root\r"
expect "Password:"
send "rootpassword\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "whoami\r"
expect -re $prompt

# and to exit
send "exit\r"      ;# exit su
expect -re $prompt
send "exit\r"      ;# exit ssh
expect eof
```